# Converting this code into a button click event

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to convert this console code to  form code:

```
    public void catching(string[] args)
    {
        UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0], 2055);
        IPEndPoint ep = null;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Write("Name: ");
            string name = Console.ReadLine();
            if (name == "") break;
            byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
            udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
            byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
            string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
            Console.WriteLine(job);
        }
    }
```

I want to put this into a button `click` event:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

but I get an error with this line:

```
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(args[0], 2055);
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do? Post your error message here.

Comment: The name args does not exists in current  context

Comment: `args[0]` is the parameter you provide when calling the executable (for example: "myprogram.exe parameter1"). If you want to convert this to WinForms, you'll need to get the parameter from a textbox, configuration (app.config) or somewhere else. The parameter is `hostName`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no `args` variable like a console application. You have to place a TextBox for user input and use that value. i.e.

```
UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(textBox1.Text, 2055);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //Send the input message using a form input like RichTextBox control.
     string text = this.richTextBox1.Text;
     UdpClient udpc = new UdpClient(text, 2055);
     IPEndPoint ep = null;
     while (true)
     {
        string name = this.richTextBox2.Text;
        if (name == "") break;
        byte[] sdata = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(name);
        udpc.Send(sdata, sdata.Length);
        byte[] rdata = udpc.Receive(ref ep);
        string job = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rdata);
        this.label1.Text = job;
    }
}
```